# How can I make Ansible Playbook to Continue after IP Change?

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I have a playbook which configures Static IP Address and reboots the Server. However, the playbook is resulting in an error. Even the following code also doesn't seems working

```yaml
    - name: Creating Interface Configuration using JINJA2 Temlate
      template:
        src: templates/interface_config.jinja2
        dest: "/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-{{ nat_int }}"

    - name: Reboot Server
      become: yes
      reboot:
        reboot_timeout: 180
        
    ## Setting Fact for New IP Address

    - name: Setting Fact for New IP Address
      set_fact:
        ansible_host: "192.168.1.253"
```

Comment: Please provide the actual error message you encounter

Comment: "_How to make Ansible Playbook to Continue after IP Change?_", if using DNS and FQDN and in Ansible inventory there should be no need for that.